# Access vba how to run code to whole table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have table named schedules where I should change values of some field depending value of another field
I manage to do that running code on form (record by record) but now I like to run it outside of form
 because of mass import to database - Is it possible?
Here is part of my code:

```
If Not IsNumeric(DAY_0_DEST_0_NAME) Then  
    DAY_0_TYPE_0_OSP = 1  
Else: DAY_0_TYPE_0_OSP = 3  
End If    
If Nz(DAY_0_DEST_0_NAME) = "" Then
    DAY_0_TYPE_0_OSP = 0
End If

If Not IsNumeric(DAY_0_DEST_1_NAME) Then
    DAY_0_TYPE_1_OSP = 1
Else: DAY_0_TYPE_1_OSP = 3
End If
If Nz(DAY_0_DEST_1_NAME) = "" Then
    DAY_0_TYPE_1_OSP = 0
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest way to do this is to run some update SQL statements from a VBA procedure. And because you are altering two pairs of fields, you can do this in a small loop:

```
Sub sUpdateData()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    For lngLoop1 = 0 To 1
        db.Execute "UPDATE Table1 SET DAY_0_TYPE_" & lngLoop1 & "_OSP=3 WHERE IsNumeric(DAY_0_DEST_" & lngLoop1 & "_NAME)=True;"
        db.Execute "UPDATE Table1 SET DAY_0_TYPE_" & lngLoop1 & "_OSP=1 WHERE IsNumeric(DAY_0_DEST_" & lngLoop1 & "_NAME)=False;"
        db.Execute "UPDATE Table1 SET DAY_0_TYPE_" & lngLoop1 & "_OSP=0 WHERE DAY_0_DEST_" & lngLoop1 & "_NAME IS NULL;"
    Next lngLoop1
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Regards,